# how to Create a virtual mic in android?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, microphone

I have following requirements :

When call is received in android phone instead of streaming microphone output I want to stream a recorded audio every time I receive call. 
So that it should be like a virtual mic.

Is it possible to do this? 
Is there any API/handlers to do it?
Any references?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, there is no dedicated API for this, nor is there any possible way to do this without rooting the Android device, which can be a very long process depending on the device. I don't know much besides that, however, such as how to do this with a rooted device, so you can probably find better explanations of that from another answer or somewhere else online.